# Ideal number of task managers in a single Flink Cluster having one Job manager

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on setting up multiple Flink Clusters in Kubernetes to deploy multiple jobs. I would like to deploy the jobs in cluster mode. What would be a good number for the count of task managers in a single Flink Cluster so that the job manager handles task manager registrations well?

Comment: I like to have one TM per machine and the degree of parallelism equals to the number of the cpu cores. With this you can be sure that there is no, or at least the minimum concurrent threads on your applications. I am not sure if it also applies when you use Kubernetes.

Comment: I'm not sure where the practical limit lies, but I routinely see clusters of 40-50 task managers.

Comment: @David Anderson , I think job manager was behaving well with a cluster of 30 task managers. As we increased the number to 60+, we started seeing issues with job manager. Cluster was taking lot of time to come to a healthy state when there were cluster restarts.